# Segmented region in image created from model disappears when using openCV to convert to binary

Tags: python, opencv

I have trained an ML model to segment images into red and blue, see code:

```
# load an image
def load_image(filename, size=(256,256)):
    # load image with the preferred size
    pixels = load_img(filename, target_size=size)
    # convert to numpy array
    pixels = img_to_array(pixels)
    # scale from [0,255] to [-1,1]
    pixels = (pixels - 127.5) / 127.5
    # reshape to 1 sample
    pixels = expand_dims(pixels, 0)
    return pixels

# load source image
src_image = load_image('../../Segmentation_data/resized_raw_data/random_selection/image10.jpg')
print('Loaded', src_image.shape)
# load model
model = load_model('./model_075780.h5', compile = False)
# generate image from source
gen_image = model.predict(src_image)
```

I have then tried to convert the image from -1,1 to 0,255 and uint.8 to work with openCV contouring.

```
# Converting to uint8, 0, 255 for openCV
norm_image = cv2.normalize(gen_image[0], None, 
                           alpha = 0, beta = 255, 
                           norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, 
                           dtype = cv2.CV_32F)

norm_image = norm_image.astype(np.uint8)

# plot the image
pyplot.imshow(norm_image)
pyplot.axis('off')
pyplot.show()
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iz5W.png)

However when converting to grey scale and then binary, ready for contouring, the image disappears.

```
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(norm_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Converting to black+white
thresh, blackAndWhiteImage = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

pyplot.imshow(blackAndWhiteImage, cmap='Greys_r')
pyplot.show()
```

[outputimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n0cE.png)

Then the contouring step does not work:

```
_, contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(blackAndWhiteImage,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-419ca3d53ab8> in <module>
----> 1 _, contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(blackAndWhiteImage,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: findContours() in different versions of OpenCV return different number of values. Try `contours = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]`. 32-bit images have range 0 to 1. So scale your image by 255 and convert to uint8.